# Android Fragment ViewPager Is Recreating Options Menu

Tags: android, search, menu

I am making an android app which has a navigation drawer with fragments being loaded on navigation items.

One of the fragment is containing two tabs which is loading another two fragments via ViewPager.

Everything is working fine as expectations but the problem comes when I select another navigation item from drawer.

One of the tab has options menu but when I go to another fragment and comes back to the earlier, then options menu gets duplicated.

---

### Class LunchTabsFragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.*;

public class LunchTabsFragment extends Fragment{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lunch_tabs, container, false);

        //Setting tabs layout
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Menu"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("History"));

        //Setting pages to be loaded with fragments
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new LunchTabsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount()));

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

---

### Class LunchTabsPagerAdapter

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class LunchTabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public LunchTabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                LunchMenuFragment tab1 = new LunchMenuFragment();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                LunchHistoryFragment tab2 = new LunchHistoryFragment();
                return tab2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

---

### Class MainActivity

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    public static final int DRAWER_OPEN = R.string.navigation_drawer_open;
    public static final int DRAWER_CLOSE = R.string.navigation_drawer_close;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, DRAWER_OPEN, DRAWER_CLOSE);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            navigationView.getMenu().performIdentifierAction(R.id.nav_lunch, 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //creating fragment object
        Fragment fragment = null;

        //initializing the fragment object which is selected
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_lunch:
                fragment = new LunchTabsFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_attendance:
                fragment = new AttendanceFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_account:
                fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                UserSessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).logout();
                break;
        }

        //replacing the fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
    }
}
```

---

### Class AttendanceFragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.*;

public class AttendanceFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attendance, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("Attendance");
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabs"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_sliding"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_sliding"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_sliding_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.gaditek.life.MenuActivity"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

Class LunchMenuFragment

---

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LunchMenuFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ArrayList<LunchMenuItem> lunchMenuItemsArray;
    private ListView listItemView;
    private LunchMenuAdapter adapter;
    private String search;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lunch_menu, container, false);

        //Initializing Buttons
        Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnReview);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button a = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnRefresh);
        a.setOnClickListener(this);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(true);
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is code that inflates menu items?

Comment: I have added that fragment class which is displaying the options menu, I need to be able to hide it in all other fragments.

Comment: Exactly. You got the point.

Comment: But the problem persists when I change select another item from the navigation drawer.

Comment: I hope you've added `setHasOptionsMenu(false);` in other fragments that doesn't have menu items.

Comment: Yes I added this in the onCreate method of other fragments but once switches it sticks to the action bar and does not go away on any of the screen ....

Comment: Okay, so may be you can hide the action item in `onPause()` of that fragment and setVisible(true) on `onResume()`. Sounds good?

Comment: I'll give it a try ... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Had to use this code in each fragment in the way to the navigation action where I don't need the options bar

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
}
```